# Difference between React Router Link and history.push?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

While I was using **Link** in React Router and **history.push** method,

I realized I have used those two method without proper knowledge.

I have used **Link** tag makes user possible to go to another component, and used **history.push** to make back button available.

But hard to tell the difference except **history** method stacks a trace.

What is the difference between **Link** and **history.push** besides I have mentioned above and how to use them properly?

Comment: Plz read transcripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Link you can navigate to another "page" by wrapping it for example a button and do the redirect when clicking. Mostly this is what you probably want to do.

But in some cases you want to navigate to another "page" programatically. For example when something changes in your app that has nothing to do with clicking on a button or link.

So you can use history.push to change the url programmatically without the need to click on a button or a link.

I hope this clears it for you

Comment: I made a back button component and wire it up with history.push method in order to make user goes back. This is not programmatical change so is it okay to use history.push in this case?

Comment: I would suggest you to use the link method for this

Comment: To complicate the issue, React Router docs show [an example of using `useHistory` to create a back button.](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)

Comment: For now, m going to take the word `history` literally - if I need to go back, fine, `useHistory`. If not...